# Area of the region bounded by four vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm stuck on how to approach this problem. I have a feeling it involves determinants and linear algebra. It's to find the area of the region bounded by the vectors:

[-7,7], [5,5], [3, -4], [-5,-6]

Comment: [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are talking about is [an area for any polygon in terms of determinants](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html):
$$\left\lvert \frac 1 2 \left(\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}x_2 & y_2 \\ x_3 & y_3\end{matrix}\right]+...+\left[\begin{matrix}x_{n-1} & y_{n-1} \\ x_n & y_n\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}x_n & y_n \\ x_1 & y_1\end{matrix}\right]\right)\right\rvert$$